# Why does this grep filter not work as expected?

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, osx-mountain-lion, grep, airport

Preface: I've added `alias airport="sudo /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport"` to my `.zshrc`.

```
myuser:~/ $ airport prefs                                            [17:19:30]
AirPort preferences for en1:

DisconnectOnLogout=NO
JoinMode=Automatic
Unable to retrieve JoinModeFallback
RememberRecentNetworks=YES
RequireAdminIBSS=NO
RequireAdminNetworkChange=NO
RequireAdminPowerToggle=NO
WoWEnabled=YES

myuser:~/ $ airport prefs | grep "JoinMode="                         [17:20:36]
Unable to retrieve JoinModeFallback
JoinMode=Automatic
```

Why doesn't this `grep` filter out the `JoinModeFallback` line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because pipes only work on stdout by default. That line is an error message being sent to stderr.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know! I wish I had a good way of highlighting stderr.